# iOS running code in different versions of code

Tags: ios, conditional-statements

I am new to iOS. In one of our iOS application I need to execute function1 in iOS version => 9 and function2 to in iOS version < 9. Does the below code works on this scenario?

```
#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED < 90000
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    // when the app is opened due to a deep link, call the Tune deep link setter
    [Tune applicationDidOpenURL:url.absoluteString sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    return YES;
}
#endif

#if __IPHONE_OS_VERSION_MAX_ALLOWED >= 90000
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)app openURL:(NSURL *)url options:(NSDictionary<NSString*, id> *)options
{
    // when the app is opened due to a deep link, call the Tune deep link setter
    NSString *sourceApplication = options[UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsSourceApplicationKey];

    [Tune applicationDidOpenURL:url.absoluteString sourceApplication:sourceApplication];

    return YES;
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try [this link](https://pspdfkit.com/blog/2016/efficient-iOS-version-checking/):

but change the function : " isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion " if any .

```
if ([[NSProcessInfo processInfo] isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){.majorVersion = 9, .minorVersion = 1, .patchVersion = 0}]) {
    NSLog(@"Hello from > iOS 9.1");
}

// Using short-form for the struct, we can make things somewhat more compact:
if ([NSProcessInfo.processInfo isOperatingSystemAtLeastVersion:(NSOperatingSystemVersion){9,3,0}]) {
    NSLog(@"Hello from > iOS 9.3");
}
```